# which pg_wal files can I delete safely?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

After I issue `pg_basebackup -D /var/lib/postgresql/basebackup -l "backup main $(hostname) on $(date)" -P`, i see there are 2 ".backup' files in `pg_wal` directory. See it [image: here]. This is what `pg_archive` directory looks like [image: here].
Questions :

1. Why are there 2 files ?
2. Which WAL files can I delete safely, before the first **".backup"** file (everything on top of **96.00000028) or before the second one (everything on top of **98.00000028) ?
3. Or do I have to delete wal files (all files above the 00028) in `pg_archive` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *never* delete `pg_wal` files. `pg_wal` is the directory that contains the primary WAL files, and there will never be a `*.backup` file in it. What you can delete are archived WAL files as written by `archive_command` or `pg_receivewal`.

Assuming you are talking about WAL archives, you can delete everything before (but not including) `000000010000000000000096` if you don't need to restore backups older than the one associated with `000000010000000000000096.00000028.backup`. This can be done conveniently with the `pg_archivecleanup` utility.

You have two `*.backup` files because you performed two backups. Perhaps it was not you, but someone else.